# I have a Jenkins global variable in a string - how do I evaluate it?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I need to accept all kinds of global Jenkins variables as strings (basically as parameters to ansible like system - a template stored in `\vars`).

```
def proof = "\"${params.REPOSITORY_NAME}\""
echo proof 
def before = "\"\${params.REPOSITORY_NAME}\""
echo before
def after = Eval.me(before)
echo after
```

The result is:

```
[Pipeline] echo
"asfd"
[Pipeline] echo
"${params.REPOSITORY_NAME}"

groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: params for class: Script1
```

- the first echo proves that the `param` value actually exists.
- the second echo is the what the input actually looks like.
- the third echo should have emitted `asdf` instead I get the exception.

Any ideas? I'm hours into this :-(

Comment: Are you declaring your parameters anywhere in your Jenkinsfile?

Comment: Have you looked at my example? `def proof = "\"${params.REPOSITORY_NAME}\""
echo proof`

Comment: @MattSchuchard?

Answer (score 3):

You may want to check:
[groovy: Have a field name, need to set value and don't want to use switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7297696/groovy-have-a-field-name-need-to-set-value-and-dont-want-to-use-switch)

### 1st Variant

In case you have: `xyz="REPOSITORY_NAME"` and want the value of the parameter `REPOSITORY_NAME` you can simply use:

```
def xyz = "REPOSITORY_NAME"
echo params."$xyz" // will print the value of params.REPOSITORY_NAME
```

In case if your variable `xyz` must hold the full string including `params.` you could use the following solution

```
@NonCPS
def split(string) {
    string.split(/\./)
}

def xyz = "params.REPOSITORY_NAME"

def splitString = split(xyz)
echo this."${splitString[0]}"."${splitString[1]}"  // will print the value of params.REPOSITORY_NAME
```

### 2nd Variant

In case you want to specify an environment variable name as parameter you can use:

```
 env.“${params.REPOSITORY_NAME}”
```

In plain groovy `env[params.REPOSITORY_NAME]` would work but in pipeline this one would not work inside the sandbox.

That way you first retrieve the value of `REPOSITORY_NAME` and than use it as key to a environment variable.

Using directly `env.REPOSITORY_NAME` will not be the same as it would try to use `REPOSITORY_NAME` itself as the key.

E.g. say you have a job named `MyJob` with the following script:

```
assert(params.MyParameter == "JOB_NAME")
echo env."${params.MyParameter}"
assert(env."${params.MyParameter}" == 'MyJob')
```

This will print the name of the job (MyJob) to the console assuming you did set the `MyParameter` parameter to `JOB_NAME`. Both asserts will pass.

Please don’t forget to open a `node{}` block first in case you want to retrieve the environment of that very node.

Comment: Isn't this equal to `env[params.REPOSITORY_NAME]`?

Comment: And it does not work. I get: `org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods getAt java.lang.Object java.lang.String`

Comment: `signature : staticMethod org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods getAt java.lang.Object java.lang.String Approving this signature may introduce a security vulnerability! You are advised to deny it.`

Comment: Sorry both of you are right. Updated the answer. Works on my local Jenkins. The env[] syntax only works if your're not in sandbox mode (or in a global shared library). And of course you would not need to put it in double-quotes. What was I thinking? ^^

Comment: `[Pipeline] echo
params.REPOSITORY_NAME == asfd`

Comment: `[Pipeline] echo
variable == ${params.REPOSITORY_NAME}`

Comment: `[Pipeline] echo
env.variable == null`

Comment: `[Pipeline] echo
env."${params.REPOSITORY_NAME}" == null`

Comment: @JoergS thanks for taking the time to look at this. The value to be evaluated must be in a variable (it's parsed out of some template), evaluated and substituted in the template. I can put it in a global library, but there seem to be no problem (exception-wise) if it is inside the sandbox

Comment: Hi, if your very last example returns null then there’s no env variable named ‘asfd’. What does env.asfd return?

Comment: @JoergS it returns nothing as it does not exist. Again the problem is that i have a variable that holds `"${params.REPOSITORY_NAME}"`, including the quotation marks, and I want to evaluate that variable... Something like `evaluate(variable)`. If `params.REPOSITORY_NAME` = `'asdf'`, and `variable` = `'"${params.REPOSITORY_NAME}"'`, then `evaluate(variable)` = `'asdf'`.

Comment: Sorry but I don't think that I get your question. So you have the variable which is exactly defined like this: `'"${params.REPOSITORY_NAME}"'`and you cannot change this? In that case you could remove the quotation marks using string processing and then use the trick described.

Comment: @JoergS, Assume a `String` variable `xyz`, which holds `"${params.REPOSITORY_NAME}"` or `${params.REPOSITORY_NAME}` or `params.REPOSITORY_NAME` - i'l try all 3. How do i evaluate xyz to return the value in `params.REPOSITORY_NAME`. All the examples above use a string literal, not a variable..

Comment: Think I'm no getting closer to understand what you're asking. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

After trying all those solutions, found out that this works for my problem (which sounds VERY similar to the question asked - not exactly sure though):

**`${env[REPOSITORY_NAME]}`**