# Variable expansion in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to expand a variable in a Jenkinsfile. I first concatenate a couple of strings to create this variable and would like for it to be expanded so that it is interpreted as my environment variable.

I am looking for something like the exclamation mark `!` in bash.

```
pipeline {
    agent: any
    environment:{
        CRED_DEV_PROJ = "my_credentials"
    }
    stages {
    stage("my_stage"){
        steps{
            script{
                LST = [
                    ["DEV", "PROJ"],
                    ... some more lists ...
                for (def i= 0; i < LST.size(); i++) {
                    CRED = "CRED_" + LST[i][0] + "_" + LST[i][1]
                    sshagent (credentials: [CRED]) {

                        ... do stuff ...          

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The variable `CRED` should be expanded so that it leads to `my_credentials`, so that the line `sshagent (credentials: [CRED])` is executed correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be `env.“${CRED}“`.

See also my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51338110/4279361